# Can we update the package.xml from a python script?

Tags: catkin, catkin-package, ros-kinetic, ros-lunar, package.xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to update a package.xml from a python script? I know that you can `catkin_pkg` to parse a `package.xml` and retrieve it's contents as a `catkin_pkg.Package`. I'm wondering if there's a method to go the opposite way - if I have a `catkin_pkg.Package` and I want to create a new `package.xml`. Better still update the existing one with my changes from the script.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290170/can-we-update-the-package.xml-from-a-python-script?/) by [Sidd](https://answers.ros.org/users/22657/sidd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2018-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A package manifest is just an xml file, so any Python xml parsing library that is able to serialise back to XML should work.

I'm not aware of any support for writing our `package.xml` files in `catkin_pkg` or any of the other libraries.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2